# Defective PHP Script in Apache server - how to find out which one?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, plesk

I recently had to increase max_execution_time on my Ubuntu/Plesk-hosted Wordpress server because of a huge script I had to execute. I forgot putting it back.

Today my server randomly crashed. Site was unavailable, htop told me php-fpm was taking all the CPU, I tried killing the process but it came back ... ended up just reducing max_execution_time back to Standard, server calmed down.

Sadly I still don't have any idea which script the guilty party is, htop just says `php-fpm: pool <mydomain.tld>`

Any way to debug apache/php-fpm to find out which script it is currently executing? Apache Error log was empty, php-fpm said "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 303776888 bytes)" for  /var/www/vhosts/mysite/wp-includes/functions.php line 3721 but I am not sure:

```
/**
 * Flush all output buffers for PHP 5.2.
 * Make sure all output buffers are flushed before our singletons are destroyed.
 * @since 2.2.0
 */
function wp_ob_end_flush_all() {
        $levels = ob_get_level();
        for ($i=0; $i<$levels; $i++)
                ob_end_flush();
}
```

Doesn't seem like the kind of thing that crashes your server? Idk

Comment: Easiest thing is to check the log files. Look into your vhost configuration.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally sent the message too early, rest of the post is there now.

Comment: the reason of the high load by a particular domain's pool may be an application design used on a site, like Google or Bing search bots.